# Homomorphism between a ring which is a boolean algebra and one which is not.

Tags: ring-theory, boolean-algebra

I remember reading in a textbook that there can exist a homomorphism between a *ring* which is a *boolean algebra* and one which is not. 
Can anyone give me some example of this.

Comment: What does it mean for you that a ring "is" a Boolean algebra? Do you require $\land$ and $\lor$ of the Boolean algebra to coincide with the ring multiplication and addition? How about (Boolean) complement versus (additive) negation?

Comment: No, a ring with idempotence on product forms a boolean algebra. I want the operation to remain the same. And meet and join can be defined in terms of addition and product.

Comment: x @Anurag, okay, so you mean a _Boolean ring_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be any (nontrivial) Boolean ring (such as $\mathbb Z_2$). Then $R[X]$ is not a Boolean ring (because $X^2\ne X$).

The injection $R\to R[X]$ is a homomorphism, and so is the evaluation map $R[X] \to R$ sending $X\mapsto 0$.

If you want finite examples, choose $R$ to be finite and consider the quotient $R[X]/\langle X^2\rangle$ instead of $R[X]$.